# No puedo compilar en Visual Studio Comminity 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

Soy nuevo en c++, estoy usando Openframeworks en su última versión y Visual Studio Community 2022 como IDE pero al momento de compilar me aparece esto:

```
Operación Compilar iniciada..
1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: Proyecto: hola_mundo, configuración: Release x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8003: La propiedad WindowsSDKDir no está definida. No se encuentran algunas herramientas de compilación.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(499,5): warning MSB8003: La propiedad WindowsSDKDir no está definida. No se encuentran algunas herramientas de compilación.
1>Compilación del proyecto "openframeworksLib.vcxproj" terminada.
1>hola_mundo.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\yvals.h(17,10): fatal  error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Compilación del proyecto "hola_mundo.vcxproj" terminada -- ERROR.
========== Compilación: 0 correcto, 1 erróneo, 1 actualizado, 0 omitido ==========
========= Compilar se inició en 11:01 PM y tomó 02,761 segundos ==========
```

Comment: Asegúrate de tener instalados todos los componentes necesarios de Visual Studio

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803149/13419694